# How are member unions containing primitives and objects initialized in C++?

Tags: c++

Say I have:

```
class Foo {
  union {
     double a;
     std::string b;
  };
};
```

What will the default constructor generated by the compiler do? [My understanding of the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127454/how-do-c-class-members-get-initialized-if-i-dont-do-it-explicitly) is that primitives are not initialized but objects are. So what happens here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default constructor (as well as the copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor) for the union is implicitly declared deleted, and so is the constructor of `Foo`. [You'll see this](http://rextester.com/LPY36653) once you try to actually create an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the example too!