# C++ Constructor behaving strangely in my Linkedlist program

Tags: c++, class, c++11, pointers, constructor

Today I was taught Linked list in class and I wanted to implement it on my own.

Here's the part of the code that I wrote. Note that `traverseLL` traverses the Linked list and `insertAtEnd` inserts a new node at the end of the linked list.

**I believe I can implement Linked list logic / methods / functions on my own. But my question is**, inside `insertAtEnd` function when I create a `newNode` with the parameters - my data to be inserted, and nullptr (because inserting at the end), It inserts **garbage values** (or memory addresses maybe) in my node, **ignoring the data passed to the constructor**.

```
using namespace std;
#define NL '\n'

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;

    Node (int data, Node* nextPtr=nullptr) {
        data = data;
        next = nextPtr;
    }
};


void insertAtEnd(Node* &head, int data) {

    Node* newNode = new Node(data, nullptr);  // <---- Issue in this line
    // When I do as above, my linkedlist nodes always store garbage values and not the data being passed.

    // However, when I un-comment the below line, I get the correct output.
    // newNode->data = data;

    if (head == nullptr)
        head = newNode;
    
    else {
        Node* temp = head;

        while (temp->next != nullptr)
            temp = temp->next;

        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}


void traverseLL(Node* head) {
    if (head == nullptr)
        return;

    while (head->next) {
        cout << head->data << " -> ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << head->data << NL;
}




int main() {

    Node* head = nullptr;

    insertAtEnd(head, 10);
    insertAtEnd(head, 20);
    insertAtEnd(head, 30);
    
    traverseLL(head);

    return 0;
}
```

For example, the output for the above code when keeping `newNode->data = data` line commented, is :

```
16259544 -> 16258392 -> 16258392
```

But when I un-comment that line, my output becomes, which is intended:

```
10 -> 20 -> 30
```

Why is this happening? Even though I've defined my constructor, why is it not working?

Comment: `data = data;` - what do you think this line is doing?

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen, I understood the issue.  The line `data = data;` in the constructor should actually be `this->data = data`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause for this is the statement `data = data` in the constructor.

**Reason for this:**
Before executing the first statement of constructor, the member variables of the class are allocated memory and contain junk/default values, and when the statement `data = data` is seen the compiler changes the parameter but not the member variable.
As a result, you are seeing junk/garbage values.

To resolve this we can either explicitly specify the member using `this` or use member initialization syntax.
You can use any of the following workarounds.

**Workarounds:**
You can change your class constructor code like any of the below formats:

1.

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;

    Node (int data, Node* nextPtr=nullptr) {
        this->data = data; // we are explicitly specifying which data to use
        next = nextPtr;
    }
};
```

2. 

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;

    Node (int d, Node* nextPtr=nullptr) {
        data = d; // as the member variable and local variable are of different names, no conflict
        next = nextPtr;
    }
};
```

3. 

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;

    // use the member initialization syntax
    // Here we are initializing the data while allocating memory itself,
    // so answer is perfectly right!
    Node (int d, Node* nextPtr=nullptr) : data(data), next(nextPtr) {}
};
```

More on the member initialization and constructor:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

[How do C++ class members get initialized if I don't do it explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127454/how-do-c-class-members-get-initialized-if-i-dont-do-it-explicitly)

Hope this helps,
Thanks.

Comment: `data = data`, refers to the parameter not the class member. See eg here: https://godbolt.org/z/f7P1jT4YY

Comment: Yes my bad, ```data = data``` refers to the parameter.